# I want my code to repeat 3 times but the loop does not end. Does anyone know how I could fix this issue?

Tags: c++, repeat

Here is the code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #define repeat(n)
    #define endrepeat

    int main()
    {
    int login;
    
    char Username [4];
    char Password [4];
 
    printf("\t\tPlease enter your user name: ");
    scanf("%s", Username);
    printf("\t\tPlease enter your user password: ");
    scanf("%s", Password);

    if (strcmp (Username,"Jane")==0 && strcmp(Password,"1234")==0 || 
    strcmp(Username,"Arin")==0 && strcmp (Password,"3201")==0 || strcmp 
    (Username,"Jake")==0 && strcmp (Password,"4312")==0 || strcmp 
    (Username,"Jazz")==0 && strcmp (Password,"4456")==0)
    {
    printf("ACCESS GRANTED");

    system("CLS");
    getch();
    }
    
    else
    {
    printf("INVALID USERNAME OR PASSWORD ENTERED.\n");
    printf("\t\tPlease enter your user name: ");
    scanf("%s", Username);
    printf("\t\tPlease enter your user password: ");
    scanf("%s", Password);
    }
    int repeat;
    repeat = 0;
    do  {
    printf("INVALID USERNAME OR PASSWORD ENTERED.\n");          
    printf("\t\tPlease enter your Username: ");
    scanf("%s", Username);
    printf("\t\tPlease enter your password: ");
    scanf("%s", Password);
    repeat + 1 ;
    } while(repeat<3);
    endrepeat;
    
    return 0;
    }
```

I want the code to repeat 3 times before exiting. When I try to run the code, it continuously repeats. I'm new to coding so sorry if it's an easy fix. :) I've tried using different methods of the repeat until, but I am still having the same issues.

Comment: The best opportunity to learn a debugger. Observe how the value of the counter changes. Where is C++ in your code?

Comment: The line `repeat + 1;` does not change the variable value. I think you meant to write `repeat += 1;`. And since you're only incrementing by 1, you can use the increment operator `++repeat;`. Also, why are you not using `for` loop? You can easily have done `for (size_t repeat {0}; repeat < 3; ++repeat) { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increment the `repeat` variable like this:

```
repeat = repeat + 1;
```

or

```
repeat += 1;
```

or

```
repeat++;
```

Use brackets inside the `if` statement to separate logic and avoid getting wrong results, like this:

```
if ((strcmp(Username,"Jane") == 0 && strcmp(Password,"1234") == 0) || 
(strcmp(Username,"Arin") == 0 && strcmp(Password,"3201") == 0) || 
(strcmp(Username,"Jake") == 0 && strcmp(Password,"4312") == 0) || 
(strcmp(Username,"Jazz") == 0 && strcmp(Password,"4456") == 0))
{
```

Get rid of the `else` statement and simply use the `do-while` loop with the `if` statement inside. Or even better, you can make a separate function for receiving and validating the input. That would make everything more readable.

Something like:

```
bool requestInput()
{
   printf("\t\tPlease enter your Username: ");
   scanf("%s", Username);
   printf("\t\tPlease enter your password: ");
   scanf("%s", Password);

   if ((strcmp(Username,"Jane") == 0 && strcmp(Password,"1234") == 0) || 
       (strcmp(Username,"Arin") == 0 && strcmp(Password,"3201") == 0) || 
       (strcmp(Username,"Jake") == 0 && strcmp(Password,"4312") == 0) || 
       (strcmp(Username,"Jazz") == 0 && strcmp(Password,"4456") == 0))
   {
       return true;
   }

   printf("INVALID USERNAME OR PASSWORD ENTERED.\n");
   return false;
}


int main()
{
   bool accessGranted;
   int repeat = 0;

    do {
        accessGranted = requestInput();
        repeat++;
    } while(repeat<3 && !accessGranted);

    if(accessGranted)
    {
       printf("ACCESS GRANTED");
       // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: If I want it to exit the loop once the correct username and password are entered, do I create another if statement?

Comment: @jessi_jebbie if either the variable `repeat` reaches the value of 3 or `accessGranted` becomes `true` the `do-while` loop will terminate by itself. No need for additional `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

After you add 1 to the `repeat` variable you have to save the result, for example, like this:

```
repeat = repeat + 1
```

The shorter alternatives would be

```
repeat += 1
```

or

```
repeat++
```

In general, I would use a for-loop in this case.